# how to kill computation of a scala parallel collection

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, denial-of-service

I want to use

```
val c = collection.par.map{ f(_) }
```

This should call f in parallel to create collection c.

but, I am not in control of function f.

for some input arguments, f has a bug and goes into an infinite loop.

Some evil person outside has discovered this kind of data argument that exercises the bug in function f. So they then submit tons of them to the system as a denial-of-service attack.

So, even if I have perfect cooperation from the author of function f, it is a function doing complicated things and can have bugs.

If I have some other thread/actor/thingy running along side, then how can it stop the calculations of the infinite loop inside the creation of the parallel collection?

And related... what if I don't even know there is an infinte loop, but my code just takes a branch where it decides it no longer needs c at all, and drops all reference to my parallel collection c above. Will the computation go on forever, or will it stop when the object is reclaimed by GC?

Comment: pls fix the broken window! don't porgram around it!

Comment: I should add this detail: function f is a pure function, no mutation, no use of threads/actors/funny business. But, somebody who works for some other company writes it, not me.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. I have edited the issue to clarify (hopefully).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no good way to kill a computation within the `map` function of a parallel computation without you, yourself, building in a means of throwing an `InteruptException`. Even then, I do not know what, if anything, that might accomplish. However, if you had to do so...

```
class MyInteruptableFunction[+A,-B](f: A => B, waitCap: Long) extends (A => B){
  def apply(that: A) ={
    val timer = new Timer
    timer schedule (new MyTaskThatThowsAnException, waitCap)
    val out = f(that)
    timer cancel ()
    out
  }
}
```

Then do this:

```
val c = collection.par.map{ new MyInterruptableFunction(f, 42) } //42 is the answer!
```

It's ugly, verbose, and error prone (your task can complete and still the error can be thrown!) So if it's an "I have no choice but to do this" then do it but please, fix the problem on their end. Raise hell with their manager. Do everything you can to make their lives difficult. I'm sure you have but...

Comment: Yes, everyone says get cooperation from the writer of function f, but here is the scenario: function f author is completely cooperative. But outside some evil person has figured out that by sending a particularly structured piece of data to the system, it will exercise a bug in function f and cause an infinite loop. Hence a Denial-of-Service attack by sending lots of them, will crash the system. I want to preclude this possibility by always being able to kill the parallel activity.

Comment: I edited the original post, since the prior comment is really apropos of all the responces.

Comment: I am going to accept this solution. It encapsulates the goop nicely, so my code doesn't get too cluttered. It only uses a Timer, not thread code that makes assumptions about how the par collections use threads. I think the race condition between the f(that) and timer expiration is inevitable in any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

How do you deal with such an `f` in a single-threaded context?

Java doesn't provide very good options for handling non-termination.  The best you can usually manage is to wrap the non-terminator in its own thread and call the (unsafe!) `Thread.stop` method.  By far the superior option is to not have non-terminating `f`s in the first place.

Comment: Good point. This issue isn't really about parallel processing then. I just ran into the concern in that context.